# trouble with .htaccess url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite the following url:

```
mysite.com/content_item.php?id=35&name=bob-is-your-uncle
```

to:

```
mysite.com/content/bob-is-your-uncle
```

The problem I'm having is that my query is based on the "id". Is there a way I can rewrite this with `.htaccess` and hide the "id" without having to go into the actual application and re-code stuff?

What I have been able to do is this:

```
RewriteRule ^cotent/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ content_item.php/?id=$1&name=$2[L,QSA]
```

which results in:

```
mysite.com/content/id/name
```

I really want to hide the "id" directory and still have the db queried on that id.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short answer, Nope. Not with the way you are doing it. Your php needs the ID in a `$_GET` request to know what to pull from the DB. You will probably have to _re-code stuff_. Curious, Why bother to hide it?

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for taking a peek. This is just an example url and vars. I want to hide it because some visitors and admins will want to type in www.mydomain.com/namevariable. They won't know the id number.